# Fetching the top-x items from a related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord

I have a `Camping` which has one `Author`. An `Author` has many `Campings`.

Getting the "top 5", defined as "5 last campings" is done with:

```
@author.campings.order(:created_at).limit(5)
```

But I'd like this concept if "top 5" to be moved into the Camping model, this seems cleaner to me; after all, the `Camping` is the only one who knows what `top` is.

Something like

```
@author.campings.top
```

But how to define this on `Camping`? `@author.campings` is not a `Camping`, but an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So something like following in *models/camping.rb* does not work:

```
# Scope for "top" campings
def top(amount)
  self.order("created_at").limit(amount)
end
```

Used as

```
@author.top(5)
```

For now, I only need this "top" thing through the relation, `@author` in above-mentioned examples. For now, the definition of "top" is simply "last 5 campings", but in a next iteration this will be more complex based on amount of views, ratings or other parameters and fields on `Camping`. Which leads me to believe that `Camping` is the correct place to define "top", not `Author`.

I could add this to `Author`, but with my limited knowlegde that feels like a violation of the isolation pattern; Author suddenly needs to know about fields on Camping:

```
# Last 5 campings for this author
def top_campings(amount)
  campings.order("created_at").limit(amount)
end
```

Used as

```
@author.top_campings(5)
```

How are such relations normally solved?

Comment: I think that you last example is fine. It doesn't violate anything, just do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I named the examples wrong. Sorry for the confusion. Latest edit fixes this. I wanted to point out more clearly that @author.top_campings pulls knowledge about "Camping" into "author". I clarified that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to define `top` in your Camping class this way:

```
class Camping < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.top(count)
    order(:created_at).limit(count)
  end
end
```

When you define it as a class method, it is available through the `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so you can call `@author.campings.top(5)`

Comment: I missed the "self" class method. Moving that self from the return and into the method definition solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3 you can use [scopes with arguments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments):

```
class Camping < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :top, lambda { |amount| order("created_at").limit(amount) }
end
```

(it is the same as adding a class method to `Camping`, I guess both ways are ok, so you can choose your preferred one)

You can use the scope as follows:

```
@author.campings.top(5)
```

Comment: I prefer class methods to scopes with lambdas, but this is also a valid approach

Comment: Reading the official Rails Guides again, I found that my question is answered there already :$. They explain this with a lambda to a scope, and then explain why that is not a good idea and that a class method is the way to go. Good to have both options, though; thanks.